# Referencing a custom WinRT component breaks javascript class?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winjs

I have a javascript Windows Store application that I'm working on, and I needed to create a WinRT component for some processing. As soon as I add the reference to that component, I get a javascript error:

0x800a01bd - Javascript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action.

This occurs on a line w/ the following:

```
engine = new MyApp.Engine();
```

Which is defined:

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("MyApp", {
  Engine: WinJS.Class.define(function() {
    //constructor stuff
    //other stuff snipped for brevity
  }
});
```

I'm not even accessing any code in my custom component, simply adding the reference causes it to break. Anyone run into this? Googling/Binging has been no help.

Comment: What's he call stack of the failure? Is your WinRT component used in the constructor of your class? Is the js that instantiates this object included before the constructor is called?

Comment: which object? In my case, all I have to do is reference the WinRT component, I don't ever have to call any methods defined on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

So in my Javascript code, I had the declaration for a namespace.

In my WinRT C# component, I was using the same namespace. That namespace apparently stomps out my JS namespace declartion. I changed my WinRT component from this:

```
namespace MyApp
{
  public sealed class SomeClass
  {
  }
}
```

to:

```
namespace MyAppUtils
{
  public sealed class SomeClass
  {
  }
}
```

And now everything is good..so, Lesson: If you're using JS and a custom WinRT component, you (apparently) can't use the same namespace in both.